# IN restrictions are not supported on indexed columns

Tags: query, cassandra, docker

I pull the `cassnadra:latest` image in Docker and run the container.
When I `exec` into the container and run the following query:

```
select count(*) 
from items 
where item_id in (
   ef2ca439-ce2a-4254-96d2-dc0c3bbed85c, c190676f-c41d-4864-858a-32b4441032dd, 
   f3316854-738b-4473-a671-3301650f09be, cb88dca3-35f6-4d83-a76c-f7ef05dc4838, 
   95b1b8c9-819e-4428-a724-0bcad568a16d, 4ec691b5-ef04-444f-8f3f-3d633ca71064
) 
and created_at > '2022-03-01 00:00:00.817000+0000' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

I get this error:

> `IN` restrictions are not supported on indexed columns

However, when I install Cassandra in my host and run this command, it works correctly.

Does the Cassandra docker image really not support `IN` ?

Comment: duplicate with this stackoverflow question: [cassandra Select on indexed columns and with IN clause for the PRIMARY KEY are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558827/cassandra-select-on-indexed-columns-and-with-in-clause-for-the-primary-key-are-n)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! You need to provide additional information in your question such as the table schema and steps to replicate. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The Docker image for Cassandra works exactly the same way as package or tarball installations.

The Docker image does support the `IN()` clause but without details of the schema and replication steps, it is impossible to know what issue you're running into. Cheers!